# Jasmine test cases for mock imported model

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to Mock the model value.I am importing Userdata model in component.ts

```
import {Userdata} from '../../../../model/userdata';
```

Following is the function:

```
getUserName(element:Userdata):string{
    let retVal:string = '';
    if(element.userdetail.length > 0){
      retVal = element.userdetail[0].name;
    }
    return retVal;
  }
```

in Userdata model

```
constructor(
    public id:string,
    public name:string,
    public description:string,
    public userdetail:Array<AppUser>,
  ){}

}

export class AppUser {

  constructor(
    public id:string,
    public name:string,
  ){}
}
```

model is referred to the parameter.How can I mock the model in spec.ts?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new `UserData` mocked how you would like in your test file.

Something like this should work:

```
it('returns the first name in array if the array has length', () => {
  const mockUserData = new UserData('1', 'My name', 'description', [{ id: '1', name: 'name' }]);
  const result = component.getUserName(mockUserData);
  expect(result).toBe('name');
});

it('returns an empty string if the array does not have length', () => {
  const mockUserData = new UserData('1', 'My name', 'description', []);
  const result = component.getUserName(mockUserData);
  expect(result).toBe('');
});
```